# Django: How to get string from CharField object?

Tags: string, django-models

I have a Django model, which is essentially a list of words. It is very simple and is defined as follows:

```
class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I need the particular word as a string object. (I am replacing all the characters in the word with asterisks for a simple Hangman game.) However, I cannot seem to get the word as a string object.

I tried adding this method to the Word class, but that did not seem to work either.

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.word)
```

I get an empty string object instead of the word.

What do I need to do to get the value of the CharField as a string object? Thanks for your help.

Edit: The weird thing for me is that it has no problem returning an integer. For example, if I were do do something like this:

```
word = Word(pk=2821)
print word.id
```

... it would print 2821, the id of that particular record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're fetching the `Word` objects correctly? The line in your example `word = Word(pk=2821)` creates a new `Word` object with a `pk` of 2821 and a blank `word` field. If you've fetched an actual `Word` object from the database that has a value in its `word` field, then `word.word` should return a string. E.g.

```
>>>> w1 = Word(pk=5, word='eggs')
>>>> w1.word
'eggs'
>>>> w1.save()
>>>> w2 = Word.objects.get(pk=5)
>>>> w2.word
u'eggs'
```

Can you also verify that the words are being correctly stored in your database by connecting to it with a DB client and looking at the output of:

```
SELECT word FROM yourappname_word LIMIT 20;
```

Like I said, `word.word` should work, so the problem might lie in how you're saving or fetching your `Word` objects.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Clearly, I am still a beginner at Django. Thanks for your help.